# Is it possible to use any other format language in android

Tags: android

In android app we generally use xml to design the activities, is it possible to implement any other formatting language

Comment: The main advantages of using XML layout are separation of UI and code and easy support for unknown screen sizes. Why would you give those up?

Comment: Instead of XML layouts you can use code to put together the interface. Just to answer your question, this is not a recommendation.

Comment: You may need to take a look at the introduced [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) . It promises less code and beautiful UI

Comment: @Toonie Compose doesn't really have any less code to it.  It's a completely different paradigm for writing UI, rather than a different language-  complete creation at runtime vs static xml files.  The UI isn't going to be any more or less  beautiful-  it maps to the same thing an XML file would.  Beauty will be determined by the skill of your UI designer